# Add an anchor link to a 'plain' HTML file, without over-writing the entire site?

Tags: templates, html, links, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple site where WordPress provides the general look-and-feel, and overall page structure, but the important pages are actually plain HTML, styled by Bootstrap. These are manually created in a text editor.

To be more precise, the "WordPress pages" are actually empty pages, but the php template includes this statement:

```
<?php include "includes/foo.php"; ?>
```

Where `foo.php` is actually an HTML file with the real content:

```
<div class="container">
...page content
</div>
```

Ok, here's my problem. Some of these HTML files are now too big for comfortable viewing, and I need to break them down by linking to other HTML/Bootstrap pages. How do I do this, while retaining the template (in other words, all the WordPress stuff around the new page, the css, and so on)?

If I simply put in a link:

```
See <a href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/includes/bar.html">here</a> for more exciting content
```

Then `bar.html` is displayed, but wipes out the site - it's just a single page with no styling. I'm guessing that I have to modify the template and somehow switch between `foo.php` and `bar.hml`, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this approach is not *remotely* close to the proper way to use WordPress, so there is just not going to be a correct way to do this. However the problem is that you're linking directly to a file in the theme. This is incorrect. To create a page in WordPress you need to create a page under *Pages* and then link to that page's permalink. If you need that page to use `bar.html` then you need to create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) for that page that includes `bar.html` into it.

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried that, as it happens, and it works. New template with the required HTML, new empty page using that template, and then add an anchor link to the new page permalink. That seems to be a pretty reasonable way to use WP? I did almost try the JS solution as well (run a function to replace the relevant div), but it would be a hassle to sort out the page history (page forward /back) so I didn't bother.

Comment: As an aside, the site is Bootstrap- and JavaScript-heavy, with a lot of Ajax to/from the server, and I couldn't find a reasonable way to do all this with plain WP, hence this approach.